# How to limit the number of strings in print?

Tags: list, python-3.x, wikipedia

The following is my python3 programme to display the 12 subcategories of Wikipedia category. It prints 12 subcategories. Now, i want to show only first 3 subcategories in print. How? But in future while developing my programme, i am going to write all the 12 subcategories in a file.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:proprietary software'
content = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml')
noOFsubcategories = soup.find('p')
print('------------------------------------------------------------------') 
print(noOFsubcategories.text+'------------------------------------------------------------------')
tag = soup.find('div', {'class' : 'mw-category'})
links = tag.findAll('a')

counter = 1
for link in links:
    print ( str(counter) + "  " + link.text)
    counter = counter + 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do `for link in links[:3]:` to display only the first three elements from a list.

Comment: When i try to write output by the following code,with open('Tamil-wiki-name.txt','a') as f:
 f.write(links). i am unable to write. why?

Comment: Not sure, but you should ask another question and provide all the details.